# MsBuild C# csproj: Put dev environment platform name (Win, Mac, etc) in to a property

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

Context: A c# project (.net 3.5) shared with a team of developers who are building the project on different platforms (Win, Mac, etc). The project requires access to some reference .dll files, but depending on the devs build platform the they are in different locations.

While devs can obviously add thier own reference paths, or just copy to a `dependencies` folder, etc., it's a bit of a pain doing that.

Also, this is an open source project that gets quite a lot of contributions from random devs, and we want to make the initial build as painless as possible for them.

So, for Windows dev environments, we've made a property group that checks through several common locations for the files (even going so far as to check registry) and the result pops out in a `$(ManagedDllPath)` property. It's one less thing to do when doing a fresh clone of the repo, and devs appreciate it.

Now our Mac and Linux devs want it too; they obviously have different folder paths.

What I ideally want to do is have one property group per platform (Win, Mac, Linux) with a condition like so:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DevPlatform)' == 'Win'">
   // determine reference dll location
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DevPlatform)' == 'Mac'">
   // determine reference dll location
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DevPlatform)' == 'Linux'">
   // determine reference dll location
</PropertyGroup>
```

How do I get the dev platform OS name?

```
<DevPlatform> ??? </DevPlatform>
```

We use VS2019 or Rider IDE. We're stuck on .Net Framework 3.5 :/

Comment: Could you use environment variables for the reference paths?

Comment: There is an [`IsOSPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=netframework-4.8) method, but it works only in .NET Core and .NET 4.7.1. Btw, just a silly question, how would you like to run .NET 3.5 in Mac or Linux? Is it a mono runtime?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter: That's what we're trying to avoid. We want the project to "automatigically" work out the locations for new devs so they can just start building with minimal fuss.

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski Yes, it's Mono runtime.

Comment: @Aubergine18 afaik, mono was updated a lot during last years, after acquiring by MS, and supports .net standard now. You can try to update to the latest version, if it possible of course, and use the latest features

Comment: @Aubergine18 you could use OS-specific environment variables that are guaranteed to exist out of the box, e.g. OS=Windows_NT or WINDIR on Windows.

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski: Sadly we're stuck on .Net Framework 3.5 due to the old version of Unity engine we're modding.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Are there similar env vars on Mac and Linux? I have no idea how things work on those operating systems.